# Is their any query to select distinct values from multiple database to populate dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database lets call abc and zyz. Both have table **demoexam** contains column *Type*. Now i want retrive distinct values of *Type* into my current database drop down list ..
Right now am facing duplicate values in my dropdown list with below code:

```
$aps= mysqli_query($connect, "select Distinct type from $instit_db.demo_exam")

While($aaa=mysqli_fetch_array($aps)

Echo "<option value='$aaa[0]'>$aaa[0] </option>";
```

Comment: yes you are already using it

Comment: It's not clear at all from your example, but I guess maybe you are running the same query twice, once from each database? If the databases are on the same server you could run a UNION query to get a list from both tables in one result set, which would automatically eliminate any duplicates.

Comment: It has to fetch data base . I think union dont works

Comment: Same server but multiple database. While loop fetch each database and get values .. My worry is all database have almost same values .. I need to get unique in the dropdown

Comment: Fetch data in one array and make a distinct in php.

Comment: I think ur telling to use UNION ALL but i do have 300 db .. Tha i cant use along

Comment: Why do you have 300 nearly identical databases? That doesn't make so much sense to me. Anyway, you said you only had 2, so you have to expect that people will suggest you solutions which work for 2, not 300! It's better always to give the true situation to begin with